# std::future everywhere? Why or why not?

Tags: asynchronous-programming

I recently had a discussion with colleagues about the use of futures (`std::future` in C++) or asynchronous calls in server applications.

On one hand, if you have server logic that needs to access an API on another server, you don't want to block your application waiting on the answer.  Using `std::future` (or the corresponding asynchronous concept in another programming language) seems to be the correct answer.

On the other hand, you don't always know which local functions are going to access a remote API (especially if the implementation is behind an interface that might have multiple implementations), so you might need to have every function and method returning an `std::future`.  Futures might even leak to function parameters and data members (so in the end everything becomes a future).

What is the current trend in using constructions like `std::future`, and what is your experience with futures regarding code design (easy to design or not), code readability (some tricks or patterns), performance and debuggability?  Which advice would you give to developers that need to write server applications (or microservices) regarding asynchronous calls?

Comment: Language support for them is lacking even with async/await. Performance hit is unavoidable due to synchronization overhead. Functional language could try to pull this off.

Comment: Utilise a task orientated dispatch system. Which is the same as saying use continuations which have levers you can take control over. Apples Grand Central Dispatch, and Intel's Thread Building Blocks come to mind as examples of what I'm talking about. Of course you can always roll your own.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438736/async-all-the-way-down-well-whats-all-the-way-at-the-bottom) and its answers might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand, you don't always know which local functions are going to access a remote API

This is the assumption you need to challenge. As the programmer, you control when these calls happen. You don't need to scatter them willy nilly throughout your program. If you consolidate them, your program usually ends up more cohesive and easier to test.

This is a problem a lot of new Haskell programmers face. They end up with [IO where it isn't needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62836068/389146). Remember, you can call synchronous code from asynchronous code, so you can call a remote API in async code, then pass the result of that call into sync code for the bulk of your processing.